# Concordance of tenses in "Surtout je voudrais l’aimer sans qu’il le sût"

Tags: subjonctif, concordance-des-temps

The question is on the verbs as highlighted in this passage from the 'Alissa's Journal' section of *La porte étroite* by André Gide.

> Parfois j’hésite si ce que j’éprouve pour lui c’est bien ce que l’on appelle de l’amour – tant la peinture que d’ordinaire on fait de l’amour diffère de celle que je pourrais en faire. Je voudrais que rien n’en **fût** dit et l’aimer sans savoir que je l’aime. Surtout je voudrais l’aimer sans qu’il le **sût**.

**QUESTION**

1. Why should they be in subjonctif imparfait instead of subjonctif présent even assuming that the text wants to be in the highest register?

Let me explain what is confusing me:  I understand that, in literary French, wishing or wanting that was done in the past and as to a contemporaneous fact uses subjonctif imparfait.  For example, [this Web page](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/imperfect-subjunctive/) gives the example:

> J'ai voulu qu'il **choisît**. (I wanted him to choose.)

The same Web page says further that spoken French would express the same idea using subjonctif présent:

> J'ai voulu qu'il **choisisse**. (I wanted him to choose.)

The Gide text is however about the present; that is, Alissa is talking about what she would like right now.  So it would appear the verbs should have been *soit* and *sache* even for formal French.

I can only try to explain *fût* and *sût* by supposing that *voudrais* is a past tense for the sequence (concordance) of tenses purposes.

2. If *voudrais* were changed to *veux* then should we use *soit* and *sache*?  I.e. is the following correct in formal French?

> Je **veux** que rien n’en **soit** dit et l’aimer sans savoir que je l’aime. Surtout je **veux** l’aimer sans qu’il le **sache**.

If I am wrong in this guess, and even *veux* requires *fût* and *sût* in formal French, please explain the principle underlying that requirement.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, this is André Gide, and André Gide was quite knowledgeable about French¹, so it wouldn’t be risking much to claim he knew what he was doing.

The agreement of tenses in this case is the key: the *conditionnel*, even in its *présent* tense, in the principal calls for a *subjonctif imparfait* in the subordinate.

The reality of spoken French is quite different, though: the *subjonctif imparfait* has pretty much vanished today, and most people don’t even know how to use it properly. I am not claiming here that people are stupid: I never had to learn to conjugate the subjunctive at school, nor were we ever told how and when to use it. Even journalists and authors tend to avoid it nowadays, and they use the present tense instead, a style considered perfectly acceptable today:

> - Elle voulait que nous **allions** voir sa vache. → *Tenses don’t agree, but nobody even blink.*
> - Elle voulait que nous **allassions** voir sa vache. → *Tenses agree, but most people would smile, some would even laugh out loud¹.*

Gide’s example uses the third person, which really is where the *subjonctif imparfait* is the least strange to today’s ears and eyes, and his use of *conditionnel présent* in the principal naturally leads to its use in the subordinate.

Your second version, where **je voudrais** is changed to **je veux**, would indeed lead to **que rien n’en soit** and **qu’il le sache**, so you’re absolutely right.

---

¹ André Gide had his view on the subjunctive. This delightful passage shows that he seemed to have a clear understanding of the situation, and could see well beyond his own opinions and tastes:

> *« On risque de tout perdre en voulant trop exiger. Il importe que la langue écrite ne s'éloigne pas trop de la langue parlée ; c'est le plus sûr moyen d'obtenir que la langue parlée ne se sépare pas trop de la langue écrite. J'estime qu'il est vain, qu'il est dangereux, de se cramponner à des tournures et à des significations tombées en désuétude, et que céder un peu permet de résister beaucoup. Considérez l'aventure du subjonctif : quand la règle est trop incommode, on passe outre. L'enfant dit : tu voulais que je vienne, ou : que j'aille, et il a raison. Il sait bien qu'en disant : tu voulais que je vinsse, ou : que j'allasse, ainsi que son maître, hier encore, le lui enseignait, il va se faire rire au nez par ses camarades, ce qui lui paraît beaucoup plus grave que de commettre un solécisme. Que ne réserve-t-on l'imparfait du subjonctif au service du plus-que-parfait et du conditionnel passé (il avait voulu, ou il aurait voulu que je vinsse, que j'allasse) moins fréquent, et, partant, à la suite duquel il paraîtra plus naturel ? C'est le moyen de le sauver. - Pour quelques temps du moins. Car le subjonctif, si élégant qu'il soit, qu'il puisse être, est appelé, je le crains, à disparaître de notre langue, comme il a déjà disparu de la langue anglaise - plus expéditive et prête à prendre les devants, mais dont le français tend à se rapprocher de plus en plus. Certains le déplorent ; et moi aussi, sans doute ; mais cela vaut tout de même mieux que de voir notre langue se scléroser... »*